Issue with Nuxt’s useFetch returning null during SSR but working fine on the client
I am using Nuxt and have wrapped the useFetch function to handle API requests with a custom setup for headers, error handling, and other configurations. Below is my implementation:
// Core API wrapper
export const apiCore = (url, option) => {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
    let baseurl = runtimeConfig.public.baseURL;

    let res = useFetch(url, {
        baseURL: baseurl,
        onRequest({ options }) {
            options.headers = {
                timeout: 20000,
                ...option.headers,
            };
        },
        onResponse({ response }) {
            // Handle responses with status 200
        },
        onResponseError({ response }) {
            // Handle non-200 responses
        },
        ...option,
    });
    return res;
};

// GET request wrapper
export const GetApi = async (url, option) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apiCore(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            ...option,
        })
            .then((res) => resolve(res.data.value))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
};

When I use this wrapper to fetch data:
// Data fetching function
export const getData = async (start_time, end_time) => {
    start_time = start_time || new Date().getTime() - 86400000;
    end_time = end_time || new Date().getTime();

    try {
        let res = await GetApi('/api/data/1/10', { params: { start_time, end_time } });
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
};

// Component usage
import { getData } from '~/api/getData.js';

const res = await getData();
console.log('res:', res);

The Issue:
1.  During server-side rendering (SSR), the server retrieves a proxy object, but on the client, the value is null.
2.  When rendering on the client side, the data is fetched successfully.
3.  Using a faster API endpoint sometimes allows SSR to retrieve the correct data, but not consistently.
4.  If I call the getData function inside the onMounted hook, the returned value is empty.
What I’ve Tried:
•   Checked API response times and confirmed slower responses exacerbate the issue.
•   Adjusted the useFetch options for headers and request parameters, but the behavior persists.
•   Attempted calling the API at different points in the component lifecycle, but the SSR-client discrepancy remains unresolved.
My Questions:
•   Is this issue related to Nuxt’s server-side rendering behavior or its handling of async operations during SSR?
•   Could this be a timeout issue, and how can I configure useFetch to handle it better?
•   How can I ensure useFetch returns consistent results during both SSR and client-side rendering?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

useFetch isn't glorified fetch but a composable. It's a mistake to use them outside the places where they are supposed to be called https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/nuxt-app#the-nuxt-context . Use $fetch instead if you want to accidentally call it and not follow the whole composable approach. This applies in particular to "getData function inside the onMounted hook", you shouldn't do this with useFetch. The meaning of "but on the client, the value is null. 2. When rendering on the client side" is unclear, "client" is mentioned twice with different result
